# Conditional Distribution of Brownian Motion

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $Y(t)=[B(t)|B(s)=c,B(u)=d]$ for $t \in[s,u]$ with $0<s<u$ and $c,d$ given. What is the distribution of $Y(t)$ for any $t \in [s,u]$? What is $E[Y(t)]$ and $Var[Y(t)]$?

I know that the marginal distributions of Brownian motion are normal and that the Variance is equal to length of time, however I'm not sure how to approach the distribution of Brownian motion conditional on another.

Comment: Search for "Brownian Bridge"

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I see that the Brownian bridge is defined on the interval [0,1] and E[B(0)]=E[B(1)]=0 and Var[B(t)]=t(1-t). How can we connect that to the current case?